# If a company say they are now open for full-time entry level or something else like that, can I apply for summer internship?

Tags: job-offer

I'm a little confused. I'm currently a graduate student in NYC and plan to graduate on December this year. But now I'm looking for summer internship. I see some companies say they are open for summer internship, and some say for full time entry level, some for part time. But what I'm confused is that if I wanna find summer internship now can I apply for those that just say they are open for full time or part time? Cuz I also see some are open for summer full time internship...I mean, how can I tell if they are just looking for internship. And if they are open for full time, although I'm looking for a summer internship, can I still apply for this job now? I mean, if I pass the interview I can take the job after I graduate! Thanks many in advance!

Comment: You're confusing me a bit as well now. :) When you say graduate, do you mean this year? Or is that further down the line? Typically a summer internship is entirely different from a regular job even if both are entry level. What are you looking for? An internship for a few months over the summer? Or something else?

Comment: I'm looking for a summer internship. ①But I'm not sure full time or part time is just for regular job or could be also for summer internship. ②And although i need a summer internship now, if there is any chance for a job opportunity for a full time regular job after my graduation, can I also apply for it now?

Comment: Where are these companies? In the US, it's less common to hire almost a full year in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, it's not very common to hire almost a year in advance, although some big companies do.

You can apply for the job now, but be prepared for a lot of "our new grad hiring begins in [August]. Please check in again at that time.

You can ask if there are any internships available--it doesn't hurt to ask.
You're very late in searching for summer internships (assuming you're looking in the US), but there should still be some available.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question. If I claim I can do the job without any paid, they will be willing to accept me?

Comment: @TingweiMa Most states I know of have laws against that

Comment: OMG. It's so hard for me. I'm so late to apply for a summer internship just because of my bad English. I arrived America last August and I wanted to improve my English first so I put it off. Although my English is not good now, I still wanna find a job. I really need that.

Comment: @TingweiMa Your university probably has an office that will help you and you can ask your adviser!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can apply to various jobs. Remember, the companies with openings really need people like you: if they didn't have the need and the money, they would not advertise the job.

Be completely transparent about your school situation. In your cover letter say, clearly, that you expect your Master's or PhD degree in December 2020. Say that you are available full time until September, then part time until December, and full time thereafter. (f course give your actual schedule, not the one I wrote)

Some companies will see that and ignore your application, because you don't meet their need. Others will respond.

And, when looking for internships and first jobs, ask your faculty and fellow students for personal referrals.

**Edit** When they hire people, like you, who are finishing school, some companies make allowances for you taking time to complete your degree. That means having you work a summer, then return to work with the ink still wet on your diploma. I hired one really good coworker that way, and bigger companies often have formal new-grad hiring practices that work like that.

You cannot know this about a company unless you ask.  Apply to both kinds of positions.

Good luck, and have a great career!

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm still a little confused. If they just advertise the job as full time, or part time, does it include summer internship?

Comment: Please see my edit for my attempt to explain better.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question. If I claim I can do the job without any paid, they will be willing to accept me? Cuz I know I'm late now to apply for a summer internship!